# Unexpected directive value 'undefined' on the View of component (angular 2.0)

Tags: javascript, angular, annotations

I use the latest alpha version of angular 2.0, then i use es5 as the code for it. when i add directives into view annotation i encounter error.

plunkr:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eJqmvaiDyypPOexr0IgF

```
place.annotations = [
    new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
        selector: 'ph-place',
        injectables: [Service.Places]
    }),
    new angular.ViewAnnotation({
        template: '<ul><li *for="#place of places">{{ place }}</li></ul>',
        directives: [angular.For]
    })
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Comment from github angular 2.0 issue by gdi2290

> @VirtualOverride the problem was that the docs on angular.io are still outdated. 
>   Here's your example working with alpha.25 plnkr.co/edit/ks0Sbv?p=preview refactored it a bit and made a helper annotations in Utils. I also added the original one as old if you prefer that"

I needed to make couple of changes:

Main issue, Changed Injectables to appInjector in the directive settings, that has been changed with the new alpha version.

```
new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
        selector: 'ph-place',
        appInjector: [Service.Places]
    }),
```

Changed For to NgFor:

```
 new angular.ViewAnnotation({
        template: '<ul><li *ng-for="#place of places">{{ place }}</li></ul>',
        directives: [angular.NgFor]
    })
```

**[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/ks0Sbv?p=preview)**

Comment: @yajra Did this comment really helped solve you problem? If so How explain in by editing you answer and adding more details onto it..

Comment: This is the answer... But not explained well, i just edited it to explain well.

Answer (score 0):

The directive "For" has now changed to NgFor:

```
place.annotations = [
    new angular.ComponentAnnotation({
        selector: 'ph-place',
        injectables: [Service.Places]
    }),
    new angular.ViewAnnotation({
        template: '<ul><li *ng-for="#place of places">{{ place }}</li></ul>',
        directives: [angular.NgFor]
    })
];
```

Comment: still not working, have you tried the plnkr i provided? thanks

Comment: Yes I know, but I solved the immediate problem listed above. Now it is looking for the Places provider and you have no code for that

Comment: have you click the plnkr link? all the code is there.

Comment: its seems its already resolve. someone edited the plnkr. (PatrikJS)
https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/2248

Comment: Comment from github angular 2.0 issue by gdi2290
"@VirtualOverride the problem was that the docs on angular.io are still outdated. Here's your example working with alpha.25 http://plnkr.co/edit/ks0Sbv?p=preview refactored it a bit and made a helper annotations in Utils. I also added the original one as _old_ if you prefer that"